# Firefox 3.6 /4: display downloads in a tab instead of the separate, default window?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, browser-addons, browser-tabs

Firefox: Is there a tweak or addon that I can install to show my downloads in a tab instead of the default window?  I love my taskbar real estate, so this would save space...

Windows 7, either Firefox 3.6 or 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [Downloads in Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4526/) addon will do exactly that.

Since you're using FireFox 3.6 you may need to follow these instructions (from the download page)...

- Right click the install link and chose save link as
- Open the resulting .xpi-file with an archive manager
- Edit install.rdf
- Change line:
  3.5.*
  to
  3.6.*
  -Save the file and update the archive(the .xpi-file)
  -In firefox choose File->Open and select the your updated .xpi-file.